# Does every invertible $\mathbb{C}$-linear operator have an eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T:X\rightarrow X$ be an invertible linear operator over a complex vector space $X$ (possibly infinite-dimensional), then does $T$ always have an eigenvalue? We may assume that $X$ is a separable Hilbert space if necessary.

I know this is true for finite dimensions by the fundamental theorem of algebra, but how about for infinite dimensions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take any bounded operator $S$ [with no eigenvalue](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1173511) and choose $N$ such that $\|S\| <N$. Let $T=I+\frac S N$. Then $T$ is invertible but it has no eigenvalue.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Why would $S$ be bounded. Why not give an example $T \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n e_n =  \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_{n+1} e_n $ whose spectrum is $\Bbb{C}^*$ with eigenvectors the distributions $\sum_n e^{zn} e_n$

Comment: I am giving a counterexample. So I can start with a bounded operator $S$ with no eigen value. There are plenty of such operators on a separable Hilbert space.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: why is this operator invertible ? I see that it is injective, but why is it surjective ?

Comment: @Boccherini $I+U$ is invertible  with inverse $I-U+U^{2}-U^{3}+\cdots$ whenever $\|U\| <1$ and the space is any complete normed linear space. This is a standard result found in any book on FA.