# Invertible linear operators without eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, hilbert-spaces

Suppose $V$ is a vector space over the complex numbers, and let $\alpha: V \mapsto V$ be an invertible linear operator.

If the dimension of $V$ is finite, we know that $\alpha$ has (nonzero) eigenvalues, due to the fact that $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed.

Are there interesting examples in the infinite-dimensional case (and still working over the complex numbers) *without* eigenvalues ?

Just to be clear: $\alpha$ is supposed to be *invertible*.

Comment: Sorry, [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3297286/does-every-invertible-mathbbc-linear-operator-have-an-eigenvalue) is a better duplicate. It explains how to obtain an invertible counterexample from a counterexample.

Comment: A direct example: Multiplication with the function $\exp(i2\pi x)$ is an example of an invertible operator without eigenvalues on the Hilbert space $L^2([0,1])$.

Comment: @s.harp: but this operator is not linear ?

Comment: The operator is the following:
$$L^2([0,1])\to L^2([0,1]),\qquad f\mapsto [x\mapsto e^{i2\pi x}f(x)]$$
this is linear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does every invertible $\mathbb{C}$-linear operator have an eigenvalue?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3297286/does-every-invertible-mathbbc-linear-operator-have-an-eigenvalue) (This is @DietrichBurde's second suggestion)