# What field do eigenvalues live in?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Given a vector space $V$ over scalar field $F$, and given a linear transformation $T : V → V$, the definition of eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $T$ is:

> A nonzero vector $\mathbf{v} \in V$ is an **eigenvector** of $T$ iff there exists a scalar $\lambda \in F$ such that $T(\mathbf{v}) = \lambda \mathbf{v}$. $\lambda$ is then said to be an **eigenvalue** of $T$ corresponding to $\mathbf{v}$.

But it seems some eigenvalues escape this definition. For example, let $F = \mathbb{R}$, $V = \mathbb{R}^2$, and $T = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. Then some computation reveals that the eigenvalues are $i$ and $-i$, which do not live in $F$.

If $V$ is finite-dimensional, I can at least confidently say that all eigenvalues live in $\overline{F}$, the algebraic closure of $F$. But what for infinite-dimensional cases?

Comment: In the infinite dimensional case your point (eigenvalue-) spectrum may be empty.

Comment: @undefined No worries even in that case; All eigenvalues vacuously live within $\overline{F}$.

Comment: Some infinite dimensional operators do not have any eigenvalues. E.g $(a_1, a_2, \dots a_n , \dots ) \mapsto (0,a_1, a_3, \dots a_n , \dots ) $ is a linear operator on sequences over $\mathbb{F} $ with no eigenvalues.

Comment: As for when eigenvalues do exist, I am not sure if they have to lie in $\bar{F} $. I would bet money that they don't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no problems with the definition. If your map $T$ is defined on $\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R^2}$ then it doesn't have any eigenvalues. It is clear that there is no vector $0\ne v\in\mathbb{R^2}$ such that $T(v)=iv$, so how is $i$ an eigenvalue? (not to mention that we don't even know what $i$ is, as we work over $\mathbb{R}$)

Now, if you work over $\mathbb{C}$ and define $T$ on $\mathbb{C^2}$ then the new transformation will have two eigenvalues, and they are indeed in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I guess that the question is if the eigenvalues belong to the algebraic closure of the field generated by the coefficients of the operator.

Comment: @coudy Again, existence of eigenvalues depend on the field. Over $\mathbb{R}$ this operator doesn't have any eigenvalues, so talking about "the eigenvalues" makes no sense. Over an algebraically closed field, any finite dimensional linear map has an eigenvalue. (which is clear, because the characteristic polynomial has a root)

Comment: The question deals with the infinite dimensional case.

Comment: @coudy When the dimension is infinite, there might be maps with no eigenvalues even over an algebraically closed field. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1173511/counterexamples-for-every-linear-map-on-an-infinite-dimensional-complex-vector

Comment: This does not answer the question wether the eigenvalues are in the algebraic closure when they exist. Anyway, I am not the one that posted the question.

Comment: I also don't see how this answers the question. I didn't post it, but a good answer would be getting at whether the eigenvalues of an infinite dimensional operator necessarily lie in the algebraic closure of the field the space is over.

Comment: @DionelJaime Again, what you mean by "the eigenvalues"? A linear map is defined over a specific field, and the eigenvalues are also defined over a specific field. Most of the time you can't "extend" the map to a different field. In finite dimensions we can at some sense do that, because a matrix over $\mathbb{R}$ can be viewed as a matrix over $\mathbb{C}$ as well. But in infinite dimensions we don't work with matrices anymore. So not sure how do you want to change the field.

Comment: The answer addresses the question. The eigenvalues of a linear transformation lie in whatever field the linear transformation is defined over.

Comment: Yes, you are right.